# Running shell command and capturing the output

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I want to write a function that will execute a shell command and return its output **as a string**, no matter, is it an error or success message. I just want to get the same result that I would have gotten with the command line.

What would be a code example that would do such a thing?

For example:

```
def run_command(cmd):
    # ??????

print run_command('mysqladmin create test -uroot -pmysqladmin12')
# Should output something like:
# mysqladmin: CREATE DATABASE failed; error: 'Can't create database 'test'; database exists'
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924310/whats-a-good-equivalent-to-pythons-subprocess-check-call-that-returns-the-conte

Comment: The duplicate at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431673/how-to-get-the-output-from-os-system explains why you can't use `os.system` here, if that's your actual question.

Answer (score 1906, accepted):

In all officially maintained versions of Python, the simplest approach is to use the [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'])
b'total 0\n-rw-r--r--  1 memyself  staff  0 Mar 14 11:04 files\n'
```

`check_output` runs a single program that takes only arguments as input.<sup>1</sup> It returns the result exactly as printed to `stdout`. If you need to write input to `stdin`, skip ahead to the `run` or `Popen` sections. If you want to execute complex shell commands, see the note on `shell=True` at the end of this answer.

The `check_output` function works in all officially maintained versions of Python. But for more recent versions, a more flexible approach is available.

#### Modern versions of Python (3.5 or higher): `run`

If you're using **Python 3.5+**, and **do not need backwards compatibility**, the new [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) function is recommended by the official documentation for most tasks. It provides a very general, high-level API for the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. To capture the output of a program, pass the `subprocess.PIPE` flag to the `stdout` keyword argument. Then access the `stdout` attribute of the returned [`CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) object:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> result = subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> result.stdout
b'total 0\n-rw-r--r--  1 memyself  staff  0 Mar 14 11:04 files\n'
```

The return value is a `bytes` object, so if you want a proper string, you'll need to `decode` it. Assuming the called process returns a UTF-8-encoded string:

```
>>> result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
'total 0\n-rw-r--r--  1 memyself  staff  0 Mar 14 11:04 files\n'
```

This can all be compressed to a one-liner if desired:

```
>>> subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
'total 0\n-rw-r--r--  1 memyself  staff  0 Mar 14 11:04 files\n'
```

If you want to pass input to the process's `stdin`, you can pass a `bytes` object to the `input` keyword argument:

```
>>> cmd = ['awk', 'length($0) > 5']
>>> ip = 'foo\nfoofoo\n'.encode('utf-8')
>>> result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, input=ip)
>>> result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
'foofoo\n'
```

You can capture errors by passing `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` (capture to `result.stderr`) or `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` (capture to `result.stdout` along with regular output). If you want `run` to throw an exception when the process returns a nonzero exit code, you can pass `check=True`. (Or you can check the `returncode` attribute of `result` above.) When security is not a concern, you can also run more complex shell commands by passing `shell=True` as described at the end of this answer.

Later versions of Python streamline the above further. In Python 3.7+, the above one-liner can be spelled like this:

```
>>> subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
'total 0\n-rw-r--r--  1 memyself  staff  0 Mar 14 11:04 files\n'
```

Using `run` this way adds just a bit of complexity, compared to the old way of doing things. But now you can do almost anything you need to do with the `run` function alone.

#### Older versions of Python (3-3.4): more about `check_output`

If you are using an older version of Python, or need modest backwards compatibility, you can use the `check_output` function as briefly described above. It has been available since Python 2.7.

```
subprocess.check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
```

It takes takes the same arguments as `Popen` (see below), and returns a string containing the program's output. The beginning of this answer has a more detailed usage example. In Python 3.5+, `check_output` is equivalent to executing `run` with `check=True` and `stdout=PIPE`, and returning just the `stdout` attribute.

You can pass `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to ensure that error messages are included in the returned output. When security is not a concern, you can also run more complex shell commands by passing `shell=True` as described at the end of this answer.

If you need to pipe from `stderr` or pass input to the process, `check_output` won't be up to the task. See the `Popen` examples below in that case.

#### Complex applications and legacy versions of Python (2.6 and below): `Popen`

If you need deep backwards compatibility, or if you need more sophisticated functionality than `check_output` or `run` provide, you'll have to work directly with `Popen` objects, which encapsulate the low-level API for subprocesses.

The `Popen` constructor accepts either **a single command** without arguments, or **a list** containing a command as its first item, followed by any number of arguments, each as a separate item in the list. [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) can help parse strings into appropriately formatted lists. `Popen` objects also accept a [host of different arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for process IO management and low-level configuration.

To send input and capture output, `communicate` is almost always the preferred method. As in:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], 
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Or

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
...                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out, err = p.communicate()
>>> print out
.
..
foo
```

If you set `stdin=PIPE`, `communicate` also allows you to pass data to the process via `stdin`:

```
>>> cmd = ['awk', 'length($0) > 5']
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
...                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
...                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out, err = p.communicate('foo\nfoofoo\n')
>>> print out
foofoo
```

Note [Aaron Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21867841/577088), which indicates that on some systems, you may need to set `stdout`, `stderr`, and `stdin` all to `PIPE` (or `DEVNULL`) to get `communicate` to work at all.

In some rare cases, you may need complex, real-time output capturing. [Vartec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760274/577088)'s answer suggests a way forward, but methods other than `communicate` are prone to deadlocks if not used carefully.

As with all the above functions, when security is not a concern, you can run more complex shell commands by passing `shell=True`.

#### Notes

**1. Running shell commands: the `shell=True` argument**

Normally, each call to `run`, `check_output`, or the `Popen` constructor executes a *single program*. That means no fancy bash-style pipes. If you want to run complex shell commands, you can pass `shell=True`, which all three functions support. For example:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output('cat books/* | wc', shell=True, text=True)
' 1299377 17005208 101299376\n'
```

However, doing this raises [security concerns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations). If you're doing anything more than light scripting, you might be better off calling each process separately, and passing the output from each as an input to the next, via

```
run(cmd, [stdout=etc...], input=other_output)
```

Or

```
Popen(cmd, [stdout=etc...]).communicate(other_output)
```

The temptation to directly connect pipes is strong; resist it. Otherwise, you'll likely see deadlocks or have to do hacky things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341451/piping-together-several-subprocesses).

Comment: Both with `check_output()` and `communicate()` you have to wait until the process is done, with `poll()` you're getting output as it comes. Really depends what you need.

Comment: Not sure if this only applies to later versions of Python, but the variable `out` was of type `<class 'bytes'>` for me. In order to get the output as a string I had to decode it before printing like so:
`out.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: @PolyMesh: `out` is `bytes` on all Python versions unless `universal_newlines=True` on Python 3. The `print` statement clearly indicates that it is Python 2 code where `bytes = str`.

Comment: @senderle You said "don't pass stderr=subprocess.PIPE" and then your examples did exactly that.  What did you mean? Thanks.

Comment: // , Is there a way to do this with STDOUT and STDERR instead of PIPE?

Comment: You could use the shell=True option and then enter you command with all the options
cmd = "ls -lh"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

Gives
('total 12K\n-rw-r--r-- 1 dokwii dokwii 3.4K Apr 19 16:57 routes.py\ndrwxr-xr-x 5 dokwii dokwii 4.0K Apr 15 16:41 static\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 dokwii dokwii 4.0K Apr 18 10:23 templates\n',
 None)

Comment: How can I do this, if I have multiple subprocess?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683445/python-subprocess-handle-exception

Comment: @senderle It fails if I use pipe and grep to capture particular portion of the output. `ps aux | grep /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess | grep webcal | grep -oE org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx[0-9][0-9]+x[0-9]+` What would be proper way to deal with this kind of command?

Comment: I am slightly confused by the way subprocess expects its input. Why do I need to split my linux command into an array of arguments. What if I want python to run a string as a command in a bash environment as a black box and just wait for the output and capture it?
I just dont understand the additional complexity and wish we could still use the commands.getstatusoutput which is now deprecated

Comment: @Parsa See [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) for a discussion.

Comment: @Khurshid The obvious quick fix is to run that with `shell=True` but a much more efficient and elegant solution is to run only `ps` is a subprocess and do the filtering in Python. (You really should refactor those repeated `grep`s if you decide to keep it in shell.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think most people are looking for the `subprocess.check_output('cat books/* | wc', shell=True, text=True)` functionality so if you can just put that at the top of your post it will be very helpful.

Comment: @Digio `cat` has to open the file, so why not do it in Python? And it's more robust to to count lines in Python.

Comment: `subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')` gives me `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 175: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 208):

This is way easier, but only works on Unix (including Cygwin) and Python2.7.

```
import commands
print commands.getstatusoutput('wc -l file')
```

It returns a tuple with the (return_value, output).

For a solution that works in both Python2 and Python3, use the `subprocess` module instead:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
output = Popen(["date"],stdout=PIPE)
response = output.communicate()
print response
```

Comment: Deprecated now, but very useful for old python versions without subprocess.check_output

Comment: Note that this is Unix-specific. It will for example fail on Windows.

Comment: +1 I have to work on ancient version of python 2.4 and this was VERY helpful

Answer (score 176):

`python3` offers `subprocess.getoutput()`:

```py
import subprocess
output = subprocess.getoutput("ls -l")
print(output)
```

Comment: It returns the output of command as string, as simple as that

Comment: Note that this explicitly marked as a [legacy function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#legacy-shell-invocation-functions) with poor support for exception handling and no security guarantees.

Comment: This offers no benefits over `subprocess.check_output` except being a few characters shorter, but given the drawbacks, that should hardly sway you.

Comment: Hey @PranavPatil, are you using linux? can you share the output of "which ls" command?

Comment: After that, splitting lines of output string can be helpful: `for line in output.splitlines(): print(line)` or words: `for word in output.split(): print(word)`

Answer (score 129):

Something like that:

```
def runProcess(exe):    
    p = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while(True):
        # returns None while subprocess is running
        retcode = p.poll() 
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        yield line
        if retcode is not None:
            break
```

Note, that I'm redirecting stderr to stdout, it might not be exactly what you want, but I want error messages also.

This function **yields line by line as they come** (normally you'd have to wait for subprocess to finish to get the output as a whole).

For your case the usage would be:

```
for line in runProcess('mysqladmin create test -uroot -pmysqladmin12'.split()):
    print line,
```

Comment: Be sure to implement some sort of active loop to get the output to avoid the potential deadlock in `wait` and `call` functions.

Comment: @Silver Light: your process is probably waiting for input from the user.  Try providing a `PIPE` value for `stdin` and closing that file as soon as `Popen` returns.

Comment: @Andre: yeah, actually in my production code I'm using threading.Timer() to execute p.terminate() upon timeout.

Comment: -1: it is an infinite loop the if `retcode` is `0`. The check should be `if retcode is not None`. You should not yield empty strings (even an empty line is at least one symbol '\n'): `if line: yield line`. Call `p.stdout.close()` at the end.

Comment: This does not work if more than one line is returned at once, better to use `readlines()` (note the `s`) instead.

Comment: btw, you could just return `iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')` from runProcess() instead of the while loop.

Comment: I tried the code with ls -l /dirname and it breaks after listing two files while there are much more files in the directory

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: `.readlines()` won't return until *all* output is read and therefore it breaks for large output that does not fit in memory. Also to avoid missing buffered data after the subprocess exited there should be an analog of `if retcode is not None: yield from  p.stdout.readlines(); break`

Comment: You exit loop when process is finished. Isn't it possible that at that moment stdout is not empty yet? (because of buffering or whatever else).
Why not to exit when readline returns empty bytes?

Comment: @jfs Thank you so much for the tip to add `p.stdout.close()` at the end; this was necessary for my script to continue running after this function call.

Answer (score 88):

This is a **tricky** but **super simple** solution which works in many situations:

```py
import os
os.system('sample_cmd > tmp')
print(open('tmp', 'r').read())
```

A temporary file(here is tmp) is created with the output of the command and you can read from it your desired output.

Extra note from the comments:
You can remove the tmp file in the case of one-time job. If you need to do this several times, there is no need to delete the tmp.

```py
os.remove('tmp')
```

Comment: Hacky but super simple + works anywhere .. can combine it with `mktemp` to make it work in threaded situations I guess

Comment: Maybe the fastest method, but better add `os.remove('tmp')` to make it "fileless".

Comment: @XuMuK You're right in the case of a one-time job. If it is a repetitive work maybe deleting is not necessary

Comment: bad for concurrency, bad for reentrant functions, bad for not leaving the system as it was before it started ( no cleanup )

Comment: @2mia Obviously it's easy for a reason! If you want to use the file as a kind of shared memory for concurrent reads and writes, this is not a good choice. But, for s.th. like having the output of a command (e.g. ls or find or ...) it can be a good and fast choice. B.t.w. if you need a fast solution for a simple problem it's the best I think. If you need a pipeline, subprocess works for you more efficient.

Comment: I was exactly looking for something like this!

Comment: I ran into contexts with multiple levels of nested sub processes where I couldn't seem to directly poll those streams or inherit a file descriptor, etc.  The principle illustrated here solved the problem.  Note it might be easier in some cases to generate a shell / batch file for a complex command, execute that with the stream redirections on the outside of it, and then delete the script.

Comment: Depending upon what you are doing, note that rather than using a temp file for the output, you might start a logger in your parent script, but when using this method, close that logger / file and than use `>>` (append) in your system call to that file.  Then restart your logger (also in append mode) after the sub process has completed.

Answer (score 77):

[Vartec's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760274/577088) answer doesn't read all lines, so I made a version that did:

```
def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')
```

Usage is the same as the accepted answer:

```
command = 'mysqladmin create test -uroot -pmysqladmin12'.split()
for line in run_command(command):
    print(line)
```

Comment: you could use `return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')` instead of the while loop

Comment: That is a pretty cool use of iter, didn't know that! I updated the code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure stdout keeps all output, it's a stream object with a buffer. I use a very similar technique to deplete all remaining output after a Popen have completed, and in my case, using poll() and readline during the execution to capture output live also.

Comment: I've removed my misleading comment. I can confirm, `p.stdout.readline()` may return the non-empty previously-buffered output even if the child process have exited already (`p.poll()` is not `None`).

Comment: This code doesn't work.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340877/why-does-this-bash-call-from-python-not-work

Comment: @thang: `shell=False`  by default and therefore you should pass the command as a list (not as a string). I've updated the answer to add missing `.split()`.

Comment: How do you get the exit code (as returned by "echo $?") of  the command you run?

Answer (score 30):

You can use following commands to run any shell command. I have used them on ubuntu.

```
import os
os.popen('your command here').read()
```

**Note:** This is deprecated since python 2.6. Now you must use `subprocess.Popen`. Below is the example

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("Your command", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print p.split("\n")
```

Comment: Deprecated since version 2.6 – https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen

Comment: @FilippoVitale Thanks. I did not know that it is deprecated.

Comment: According to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71547/is-there-a-problem-with-using-deprecated-os-popen `os.popen()` is deprecated in Python 2.6, but it is *not* deprecated in Python 3.x, since in 3.x it is implemented using `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: ... But you want to avoid `subprcess.Popen` too for simple tasks that `subprocess.check_output` and friends can handle with much less code and better robustness. This has multiple bugs for nontrivial commands.

Comment: `print ` isn't a command. Do you mean `print()`?

Comment: @beedell.rokejulianlockhart yes. Its an old answer. Was working on Python 2.7 at that time so wrote according to that.

Answer (score 17):

On **Python 3.7+**, use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and pass `capture_output=True`:

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['echo', 'hello', 'world'], capture_output=True)
print(repr(result.stdout))
```

This will return bytes:

```
b'hello world\n'
```

If you want it to convert the bytes to a string, add `text=True`:

```py
result = subprocess.run(['echo', 'hello', 'world'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(repr(result.stdout))
```

This will read the bytes using your default encoding:

```
'hello world\n'
```

If you need to manually specify a different encoding, use `encoding="your encoding"` instead of `text=True`:

```py
result = subprocess.run(['echo', 'hello', 'world'], capture_output=True, encoding="utf8")
print(repr(result.stdout))
```

Comment: This is the best answer today.

Answer (score 14):

**I had a slightly different flavor of the same problem with the following requirements:**

1. Capture and return STDOUT messages as they accumulate in the STDOUT buffer (i.e. in realtime).

   - *@vartec solved this Pythonically with his use of generators and the 'yield'

     keyword above*
2. Print all STDOUT lines (*even if process exits before STDOUT buffer can be fully read*)
3. Don't waste CPU cycles polling the process at high-frequency
4. Check the return code of the subprocess
5. Print STDERR (separate from STDOUT) if we get a non-zero error return code.

**I've combined and tweaked previous answers to come up with the following:**

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell=True)
    # Read stdout from subprocess until the buffer is empty !
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        if line: # Don't print blank lines
            yield line
    # This ensures the process has completed, AND sets the 'returncode' attr
    while p.poll() is None:                                                                                                                                        
        sleep(.1) #Don't waste CPU-cycles
    # Empty STDERR buffer
    err = p.stderr.read()
    if p.returncode != 0:
       # The run_command() function is responsible for logging STDERR 
       print("Error: " + str(err))
```

**This code would be executed the same as previous answers:**

```
for line in run_command(cmd):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how the addition of sleep(.1) won't waste CPU cycles?

Comment: If we continued to call ``p.poll()`` without any sleep in between calls, we would waste CPU cycles by calling this function millions of times. Instead, we "throttle" our loop by telling the OS that we don't need to be bothered for the next 1/10th second, so it can carry out other tasks. (It's possible that p.poll() sleeps too, making our sleep statement redundant).

Answer (score 12):

Your Mileage May Vary, I attempted @senderle's spin on Vartec's solution in Windows on Python 2.6.5, but I was getting errors, and no other solutions worked. My error was: `WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid`.

I found that I had to assign PIPE to every handle to get it to return the output I expected - the following worked for me.

```
import subprocess

def run_command(cmd):
    """given shell command, returns communication tuple of stdout and stderr"""
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

and call like this, (`[0]` gets the first element of the tuple, `stdout`):

```
run_command('tracert 11.1.0.1')[0]
```

After learning more, I believe I need these pipe arguments because I'm working on a custom system that uses different handles, so I had to directly control all the std's.

To stop console popups (with Windows), do this:

```
def run_command(cmd):
    """given shell command, returns communication tuple of stdout and stderr"""
    # instantiate a startupinfo obj:
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    # set the use show window flag, might make conditional on being in Windows:
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    # pass as the startupinfo keyword argument:
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            startupinfo=startupinfo).communicate()

run_command('tracert 11.1.0.1')
```

Comment: Interesting -- this must be a Windows thing. I'll add a note pointing to this in case people are getting similar errors.

Comment: use [`DEVNULL` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279) of `subprocess.PIPE` if you don't write/read from a pipe otherwise you may hang the child process.

Answer (score 9):

Splitting the initial command for the `subprocess` might be tricky and cumbersome.

Use `shlex.split()` to help yourself out.

**Sample command**

`git log -n 5 --since "5 years ago" --until "2 year ago"`

**The code**

```
from subprocess import check_output
from shlex import split

res = check_output(split('git log -n 5 --since "5 years ago" --until "2 year ago"'))
print(res)
>>> b'commit 7696ab087a163e084d6870bb4e5e4d4198bdc61a\nAuthor: Artur Barseghyan...'
```

**Without `shlex.split()` the code would look as follows**

```py
res = check_output([
    'git', 
    'log', 
    '-n', 
    '5', 
    '--since', 
    '5 years ago', 
    '--until', 
    '2 year ago'
])
print(res)
>>> b'commit 7696ab087a163e084d6870bb4e5e4d4198bdc61a\nAuthor: Artur Barseghyan...'
```

Comment: `shlex.split()` is a convenience, especially if you don't know how exactly quoting in the shell works; but manually converting this string to the list `['git', 'log', '-n', '5', '--since', '5 years ago', '--until', '2 year ago']` is not hard at all if you understand quoting.

Answer (score 6):

Here a solution, working if you want to print output while process is running or not.

---

I added the current working directory also, it was useful to me more than once.

---

Hoping the solution will help someone :).

```
import subprocess

def run_command(cmd_and_args, print_constantly=False, cwd=None):
"""Runs a system command.

:param cmd_and_args: the command to run with or without a Pipe (|).
:param print_constantly: If True then the output is logged in continuous until the command ended.
:param cwd: the current working directory (the directory from which you will like to execute the command)
:return: - a tuple containing the return code, the stdout and the stderr of the command
"""
output = []

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_and_args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=cwd)

while True:
    next_line = process.stdout.readline()
    if next_line:
        output.append(str(next_line))
        if print_constantly:
            print(next_line)
    elif not process.poll():
        break

error = process.communicate()[1]

return process.returncode, '\n'.join(output), error
```

Comment: Working both on python 3 and 2.7

Comment: This deadlocks if the process writes a significant amount of output on standard error.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, this one works on Python 2.7 and you only need to import os!

```py
import os 

def bash(command):
    output = os.popen(command).read()
    return output

print_me = bash('ls -l')
print(print_me)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to run a shell command on multiple files, this did the trick for me.

```
import os
import subprocess

# Define a function for running commands and capturing stdout line by line
# (Modified from Vartec's solution because it wasn't printing all lines)
def runProcess(exe):    
    p = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')

# Get all filenames in working directory
for filename in os.listdir('./'):
    # This command will be run on each file
    cmd = 'nm ' + filename

    # Run the command and capture the output line by line.
    for line in runProcess(cmd.split()):
        # Eliminate leading and trailing whitespace
        line.strip()
        # Split the output 
        output = line.split()

        # Filter the output and print relevant lines
        if len(output) > 2:
            if ((output[2] == 'set_program_name')):
                print filename
                print line
```

Edit: Just saw Max Persson's solution with J.F. Sebastian's suggestion.  Went ahead and incorporated that.

Comment: `Popen` accepts either a string, but then you need `shell=True`, or a list of arguments, in which case you should pass in `['nm', filename]` instead of a string. The latter is preferable because the shell adds complexity without providing any value here. Passing a string without `shell=True` apparently happens to work on Windows, but that could change in any next Python version.

Answer (score 5):

According to @senderle, if you use python3.6 like me:

```
def sh(cmd, input=""):
    rst = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, input=input.encode("utf-8"))
    assert rst.returncode == 0, rst.stderr.decode("utf-8")
    return rst.stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

```
sh("ls -a")
```

Will act exactly like you run the command in bash

Comment: You are reinventing the keyword arguments `check=True, universal_newlines=True`. In other words `subprocess.run()` already does everything your code does.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use the function `subprocess.check_output`

For example, the following function captures stdout and stderr of the process and returns that as well as whether or not the call succeeded.  It is Python 2 and 3 compatible:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError, STDOUT

def system_call(command):
    """ 
    params:
        command: list of strings, ex. `["ls", "-l"]`
    returns: output, success
    """
    try:
        output = check_output(command, stderr=STDOUT).decode()
        success = True 
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        output = e.output.decode()
        success = False
    return output, success

output, success = system_call(["ls", "-l"])
```

If you want to pass commands as strings rather than arrays, use this version:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError, STDOUT
import shlex

def system_call(command):
    """ 
    params:
        command: string, ex. `"ls -l"`
    returns: output, success
    """
    command = shlex.split(command)
    try:
        output = check_output(command, stderr=STDOUT).decode()
        success = True 
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        output = e.output.decode()
        success = False
    return output, success

output, success = system_call("ls -l")
```

Comment: I was browsing for ideas and gave yours a try. Very nice and looks pretty compact too, which makes it easier to read the code later.
THX

Answer (score 2):

Improvement for better logging. 
For better output you can use iterator.
From below, we get better

```
from subprocess import Popen, getstatusoutput, PIPE
def shell_command(cmd):
    result = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    output = iter(result.stdout.readline, b'')
    error = iter(result.stderr.readline, b'')
    print("##### OutPut ###")
    for line in output:
        print(line.decode("utf-8"))
    print("###### Error ########")
    for line in error:
        print(error.decode("utf-8")) # Convert bytes to str

    status, terminal_output = run_command(cmd)
    print(terminal_output)

shell_command("ls") # this will display all the files & folders in directory
```

Other method using getstatusoutput ( Easy to understand)

```
from subprocess import Popen, getstatusoutput, PIPE

status_Code, output = getstausoutput(command)
print(output) # this will give the terminal output

# status_code, output = getstatusoutput("ls") # this will print the all files & folder available in the directory
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `subprocess` python module, you are able to handle the STDOUT, STDERR and return code of command separately. You can see an example for the complete command caller implementation. Of course you can extend it with `try..except` if you want.

The below function returns the STDOUT, STDERR and Return code so you can handle them in the other script.

```
import subprocess

def command_caller(command=None)
    sp = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    out, err = sp.communicate()
    if sp.returncode:
        print(
            "Return code: %(ret_code)s Error message: %(err_msg)s"
            % {"ret_code": sp.returncode, "err_msg": err}
            )
    return sp.returncode, out, err
```

Comment: Another poor reimplementation of `subprocess.run()`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest [simppl](https://pypi.org/project/simppl/) as an option for consideration. It is a module that is available via pypi: `pip install simppl` and was runs on python3.

[`simppl`](https://github.com/nrgene/simppl) allows the user to run shell commands and read the output from the screen.

The developers suggest three types of use cases:

> 1. The simplest usage will look like this:
>
> ````
>     from simppl.simple_pipeline import SimplePipeline
>     sp = SimplePipeline(start=0, end=100):
>     sp.print_and_run('<YOUR_FIRST_OS_COMMAND>')
>     sp.print_and_run('<YOUR_SECOND_OS_COMMAND>') ```
> ````

---

> 2. To run multiple commands concurrently use:
>
> ````
>     commands = ['<YOUR_FIRST_OS_COMMAND>', '<YOUR_SECOND_OS_COMMAND>']
>     max_number_of_processes = 4
>     sp.run_parallel(commands, max_number_of_processes) ```
> ````

---

> 3. Finally, if your project uses the cli module, you can run directly another command_line_tool as part of a pipeline. The other tool will
>    be run from the same process, but it will appear from the logs as
>    another command in the pipeline. This enables smoother debugging and
>    refactoring of tools calling other tools.
>
> ````
>     from example_module import example_tool
>     sp.print_and_run_clt(example_tool.run, ['first_number', 'second_nmber'], 
>                                  {'-key1': 'val1', '-key2': 'val2'},
>                                  {'--flag'}) ```
> ````

Note that the printing to STDOUT/STDERR is via python's `logging` module.

---

Here is a complete code to show how simppl works:

```
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

logging_config = dict(
    version = 1,
    formatters = {
        'f': {'format':
              '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'}
        },
    handlers = {
        'h': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
              'formatter': 'f',
              'level': logging.DEBUG}
        },
    root = {
        'handlers': ['h'],
        'level': logging.DEBUG,
        },
)
dictConfig(logging_config)

from simppl.simple_pipeline import SimplePipeline
sp = SimplePipeline(0, 100)
sp.print_and_run('ls')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and flexible solution that works on a variety of OS versions, and both Python 2 and 3, using IPython in shell mode:

```
from IPython.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed
my_shell = InteractiveShellEmbed()
result = my_shell.getoutput("echo hello world")
print(result)

Out: ['hello world']
```

It has a couple of advantages

1. It only requires an IPython install, so you don't really need to worry about your specific Python or OS version when using it, it comes with Jupyter - which has a wide range of support
2. It takes a simple string by default - so no need to use shell mode arg or string splitting, making it slightly cleaner IMO
3. It also makes it cleaner to easily substitute variables or even entire Python commands in the string itself

---

To demonstrate:

```
var = "hello world "
result = my_shell.getoutput("echo {var*2}")
print(result)

Out: ['hello world hello world']
```

Just wanted to give you an extra option, especially if you already have Jupyter installed

Naturally, if you are in an actual Jupyter notebook as opposed to a .py script you can also always do:

```
result = !echo hello world
print(result)
```

To accomplish the same.

Comment: This sort of string construction is a bad idea for safety and reliability.  The other answers here include various options that use only the standard library, so it's hard to argue that this is more portable.

Comment: By "portable" I mean "runs the same in every environment". The other answers here rely on using different steps for different versions of Python, and different environments. Additionally, their failure conditions differ based on approach. For example, check_output based approaches will fail to yield any output if the underlying process fails, while other subprocess approaches will not. The above solution is agnostic to environment and version - and consistently yields the same result you would get as if you ran it in shell yourself, even during failure, which is what I think the user expects.

Comment: w.r.t. string construction - I agree it can be dangerous in production scenarios. But other scenarios - such as exploratory data analysis - value code efficiency over safety, as they are not going directly to production. Such string construction has value in several such situations.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(shell=True)` is just as platform-independent (surely we can assume Python 2.7 or 3.1 by now!), and its `CalledProcessError` *does* have `output` available.  I certainly respect the idea that research software has different objectives, but I’ve seen plenty of it suffer from insufficient care around things like process exit codes and thus do not advocate for “just like the interactive interface” design (although I grant that it is what’s explicitly solicited in this question!).

Comment: The accepted answer does not account for CalledProcessError, despite this being explicitly what is requested by TC. Sounds like TC basically wanted a one liner, this is a true cross-platform one liner. I accept that "magic" solutions are controversial, but it can be valuable - and sometimes preferable - to know they exist. IPython and Jupyter as a project exist for explicitly this purpose, and people find those plenty valuable - unless you are arguing that IPython/Jupyter have no place in a Python programmer's workflow. It basically depends on whether TC believes in "magic" or not!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I use to support multithreading in Jupyter notebook cell and make cell printing the shell outputs, in real time. It make use of `bufsize` and `stderr`.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def verbosecmd(command):
    with Popen(
        command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=0, close_fds=True
    ) as process:
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b""):
            print(line.rstrip().decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For general use:

```
my_shell_command = 'grep "text" ' + filename
result = subprocess.run(my_shell_command, shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
print(result.stdout, end="")
```

Answer (score -1):

### 1-liner function for optimists

```
def cmd(x): from subprocess import check_output as c; return c(x, shell=True, text=True) # noqa
```

#### usage

```
out_linux, out_win = cmd('ls -la') , cmd('ipconfig')
# ... Now go Do something with the output
```

Comment: What is the purpose here?  The only reason to write code this way is to be able to run it from shell with `python -c "..."`, which obviously has no point in this case

Comment: @NikolajŠ. you have perhaps misunderstood the dummy test case with main objective. it was meant for demo only. i have omitted it. a good deal of thought went before writing, and no intentions to spam.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to capture both stdout and stderr and display them as they would appear when a shell command is executed in a interactive terminal *and* you needed to know the return status of the command, you can do a following hack.

```
import time, os
cmd_str = "ls -d /bin/nonsense"

tmpfile= "/tmp/results." + str(os.getpid()) + "." + str(time.time()) 
status = os.system( cmd_str + " > " + tmpfile +" 2>&1")
with open(tmpfile, 'r') as f:
  print (f.read())
os.remove(tmpfile)
  
print("status=" + str(status))
```

Note:
The **tmpfile** is unique and removed as soon as it is used.
Shell is used to parse the cmd_str, hence don't use this technique for arbitrary strings because it is unsafe.

Answer (score -4):

eg, execute('ls -ahl')
differentiated three/four possible returns and OS platforms:

1. no output, but run successfully
2. output empty line, run successfully
3. run failed
4. output something, run successfully

function below

```
def execute(cmd, output=True, DEBUG_MODE=False):
"""Executes a bash command.
(cmd, output=True)
output: whether print shell output to screen, only affects screen display, does not affect returned values
return: ...regardless of output=True/False...
        returns shell output as a list with each elment is a line of string (whitespace stripped both sides) from output
        could be 
        [], ie, len()=0 --> no output;    
        [''] --> output empty line;     
        None --> error occured, see below

        if error ocurs, returns None (ie, is None), print out the error message to screen
"""
if not DEBUG_MODE:
    print "Command: " + cmd

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/40139101/2292993
    def _execute_cmd(cmd):
        if os.name == 'nt' or platform.system() == 'Windows':
            # set stdin, out, err all to PIPE to get results (other than None) after run the Popen() instance
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        else:
            # Use bash; the default is sh
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")

        # the Popen() instance starts running once instantiated (??)
        # additionally, communicate(), or poll() and wait process to terminate
        # communicate() accepts optional input as stdin to the pipe (requires setting stdin=subprocess.PIPE above), return out, err as tuple
        # if communicate(), the results are buffered in memory

        # Read stdout from subprocess until the buffer is empty !
        # if error occurs, the stdout is '', which means the below loop is essentially skipped
        # A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; 
        # it indicates that the literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3 
        # (e.g. when code is automatically converted with 2to3).
        # return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')
        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
            # # Windows has \r\n, Unix has \n, Old mac has \r
            # if line not in ['','\n','\r','\r\n']: # Don't print blank lines
                yield line
        while p.poll() is None:                                                                                                                                        
            sleep(.1) #Don't waste CPU-cycles
        # Empty STDERR buffer
        err = p.stderr.read()
        if p.returncode != 0:
            # responsible for logging STDERR 
            print("Error: " + str(err))
            yield None

    out = []
    for line in _execute_cmd(cmd):
        # error did not occur earlier
        if line is not None:
            # trailing comma to avoid a newline (by print itself) being printed
            if output: print line,
            out.append(line.strip())
        else:
            # error occured earlier
            out = None
    return out
else:
    print "Simulation! The command is " + cmd
    print ""
```