# Why does 'java -version' go to stderr?

Tags: java, stdout, stderr

Is there any special reason for the results of `java -version` going to `stderr`?

For example, this command executed from Windows' prompt line:

```
java -version > java_version.txt
```

leaves the file `java_version.txt` empty.

EDIT: The same happens with the help printed out after executing `java.exe` without any parameters.

EDIT: Just out of a sheer curiosity I checked whether it has been always like that and it turned out it actually has. `java -version` goes to `stderr` in JDK 1.1.8 and also in JDK 1.2.2, however the outputs of `java.exe` without any parameters do not.

Comment: This is pretty much the norm for *NIX commands.

Comment: Sadly, `javac -version` is also odd that way. Workaround: `java -version 2>&1 | egrep 'java|version' --color`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is there any special reason for the results of java -version going to stderr?

AFAIK, there is no special reason.  It is just how the `java` command was / is implemented.  Probably all the way back to Java 1.0, though it would be very difficult to verify that.

My brief investigation shows that this behavior is *inconsistent* with how most Linux commands behave ... everything else I've tried uses stdout for version information.  (After all, the version information is not "error" output.)

Note however `--version` / `-version` options are a convention rather than something required by any formal standard.  (The [GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/_002d_002dversion.html) state that commands should implement `--version` and that version info should be written to standard output.  But POSIX standards don't mention this, nor do the LSB standards.)

---

What can / should you do?

- It should be easy to capture stderr instead of stdout in your shell script or batch file.
- There shouldn't be any risk in doing this.  Oracle cannot change the Java tool chains to send `-version` output to stdout without potentially breaking customer scripts.  This is highly unlikely<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - Here is evidence of just how unlikely it is: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4380614.  Note the "Resolution: Wont Fix" ... and the final comment.</sup>

---

**UPDATE**

In Java 9, they introduced some new "version" command line options.  If you run `java -help 2>&1 | grep version` against a Java 11 installation you will see the following:

```
$ java -help 2>&1 | grep version
    -version      print product version to the error stream and exit
    --version     print product version to the output stream and exit
    -showversion  print product version to the error stream and continue
    --show-version
                  print product version to the output stream and continue.
```

So if you are using Java 11 LTS or later, the solution will be to use `--version` rather that `-version` to get the version information.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround for this problem is:

```
java -version 2> java_version.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is helpful, however does not answer my question. I would like to know if there is any special reason behind this design.