# Redirect java -version to file or variable

Tags: java, linux, variables, redirect, command

Maybe it is a silly question, but I'm trying to redirect the exit of "java -version" command  to a file or variable but it doesn't work.

Server = Linux CentOS 6

My code in shell script

```
java -version >> test.txt
```

Also I'm trying to assign it to a variable:

```
JAVA_CHECK=`java -version`
```

Even running those command from command-line it still not working.

when I say it doesnt work, I mean that the exit of the command is being showed in my screen instead to redirect it to a file or wherever

...

Comment: its a good question - this is happening on windows too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does 'java -version' go to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483443/why-does-java-version-go-to-stderr)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`java -version` writes to stderr (fileno 2), not stdout (fileno 1). You can redirect stderr to a file:

```
java -version 2> test.txt
# cat test.txt 
# java version "1.7.0_25"
# OpenJDK Runtime Environment
# [...]
```

Or you can redirect stderr to stdout:

```
java_check=$(java -version 2>&1)
# echo "$java_check"
# java version "1.7.0_25" OpenJDK Runtime Environment [...]
```

Comment: Great it works!!. But I dont undestand why Java writes to sterr instead to stdout. And other weird issue happed when I try to assign the variable command within my shell scrip, it's works, I mean it's doing well the redirection but it's feeding my variale with "Error: Could not find or load main class version"

Comment: Probably you forgot the dash before the version: `java version` will try to run a class named `version`

Comment: Unfortunately not, the dash still there, I've copied and pasted the comand. It's prety corious because 2> test.txt works but 2>&1 shows the error.

Comment: Fascinating! Which shell are you using? Works for me on ubuntu/bash.

Comment: Well yes it's. I'm using CentOS/bash.