# Command is not running while running using java

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal

I want to run a command in Termninal(Ubuntu) using java program

After surfing in internet i found out way to execute commands using java

**Following is the code to find ldd version in ubuntu**

```
String[] command = { "ldd", "--version" };
            ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process process = probuilder.start();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            process.waitFor();

            // System.out.println(br.readLine());
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

In the above code i trying to find out "ldd verison" using java in ubuntu. which worked fine i am got ldd version.

But when i tried to find java version of my ubuntu  in the same way.
The code is returning nothing because br.readline is null. iwas abel to find out ldd vesion,**why not java version?**

**Following is the code to find out java version in ubuntu using java**

```
String[] command = { "java", "-version" };

    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = probuilder.start();

    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    process.waitFor();

    // System.out.println(br.readLine());
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Some one please help me to find out how to find java version using java code in ubuntu.

Comment: Read the error stream to find out what is happend. maybe Java is not in PATH.

Comment: Try to print `process.getErrorStream()` in the same way as inputstream. Probably you are getting an error message in that stream.

Comment: The only explanation I can conjure up is that `java` is not on your `PATH` variable.  If so, when your Java code ran `java -version` it actually errored out.

Comment: Please do update the question once you got the error message.

Comment: System.getProperty("java.specification.version") as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591083/getting-version-of-java-in-runtime

Comment: @Codebender thanks for the reply. I  printed out process.getErrorStream() i got the followoing **java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)**. java version which i was excpecting is  in ErrorStream. do you know why i am getting there?

Comment: @SamuelToh thanks for the reply. I printed out process.getErrorStream() i got the followoing java version "1.7.0_72" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode). java version which i was excpecting is in ErrorStream. do you know why i am

Comment: @Chinna i did some research for you and came across an earlier post which talks about Java's strange implementation for the `-version` option. See my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the way Java was implemented. It appears that Java's `-version` option gets printed through the `stderr` instead of the usual `stdout`

**Reference:**
[Why does 'java -version' go to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483443/why-does-java-version-go-to-stderr)

This phenomenon explains why your subprocess ran the command but seem everything is printed through the stderr channel it seems as thou it didn't failed executing the command but when you dump the error stream through `process.getErrorStream()` you see the version text instead.

You should be able to get the Java version number through the '**java.version**' system property.

**Example:**

`System.out.println( System.getProperty("java.version") );`

**Output:**

> 1.8.0_51

You might be interested in the other Java related properties that you can print - like runtime and product build version etc.

See:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/versioning-naming-139433.html