# Why aws --version writes to stderr?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Why standard check `aws --version` prints the expected output to the stderr, not stdout?

```
$ aws --version 2>err.log
$ cat err.log
aws-cli/1.11.65 Python/2.7.13 Darwin/16.5.0 botocore/1.5.28
$ aws --version > out.log
aws-cli/1.11.65 Python/2.7.13 Darwin/16.5.0 botocore/1.5.28
$ cat out.log
$
```

It would make sense to write the result into stdout if command completed successfully. Other commands like `aws ec2 describe-images` or `aws ec2 describe-instances` write the output to the stdout correctly.

Checked on CentOS and MacOS.

Comment: Some explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483443/why-does-java-version-go-to-stderr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by a [bug in argparse](https://bugs.python.org/issue18920) that was fixed in Python 3.4.

The awscli is written in Python and it uses the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) to parse the command line. It also uses the `action="version"` [feature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) of argparse to simplify version printing.  This prints the version string to stderr prior to Python 3.4 and prints to stdout in Python 3.4+.