# Capturing the system.out messages from another process

Tags: java

I have a JVM(1) which launches JVM(2). I want to be able to monitor the System.out.println() calls from JVM(2) in JVM(1).

Comment: Do you actually have two separate JVMs, or two *threads* within a Java program?

Comment: Two separate JVMs. JVM(1) launches JVM(2) but I require JVM(1) to monitor JVM(2)'s System.out messages

Comment: Please paste your code snippet from JVM-1where JVM-2 is launched, so we can find integration-points to capture output of JVM-2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straight forward way would be:

- JVM A does a system command to start JVM B
- JVM A then reads all output from B

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803664/get-output-of-cmd-command-from-java-code) for how to do that (in essence, there is no difference between calling `java SomeClass` ... or any other command that then writes to stdout/stderr).

If your two JVMs get started independently, then the only option left would be that the "start command" of B redirects all output into a file. And then, depending on the OS, you can only hope that the other JVM sees all updates to that file in a timely manner.