# Ansible: Install Python module only if it not exist

Tags: ansible, devops

I need to install Python `pip` via Ansible on a remote server. I do it like this and it work:

```yaml
  - name: Download pip installer
    get_url:
      url: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
      dest: /tmp/get-pip.py

  - name: Install pip
    shell: /usr/bin/python /tmp/get-pip.py
```

One problem - it have status "changed" every time when I run a playbook. I don't need to install it every time I run playbook.

How can I check and install the `pip` module only if it didn't installed before?

Comment: This could be helpful: [https://github.com/William-Yeh/ansible-uwsgi/blob/master/tasks/install-pip.yml](https://github.com/William-Yeh/ansible-uwsgi/blob/master/tasks/install-pip.yml)

Comment: @Zeitounator, I think that could be the answer and preferred solution.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Since a system where `pip` hasn't been installed reports with

```bash
pip --version; echo $?
-bash: pip: command not found
127
```

you could implement installation and version tests before running the download and installation task.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather installed pip version, if there is any
    shell:
      cmd: pip --version | cut -d ' ' -f 2
    register: result
    failed_when: result.rc != 0 and result.rc != 127
    # Since this is a reporting task, it should never change
    # as well run and register a result in any case
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: false

  - name: Set default version, if there is no
    set_fact:
      result:
        stdout_lines: "00.0.0"
    when: "'command not found' in result.stdout"

  - name: Report result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
    check_mode: false
    when: result.stdout != "20.3.4"
```

Resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Gather installed pip version, if there is any] ***
ok: [test.example.com]

TASK [Report result] ***********************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: 20.3.4
```

**Further Q&A**

- [Whats the best way in Ansible to check if a command is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70812235/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to install a package only if same version not installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70021491/6771046)

**Documentation**

- [Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure)
- [Defining "changed"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed)
- [Using `check_mode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-check-mode)

---

... just an example add-on with shell operators

```yaml
  - name: Install 'pip' only if it not exist
    shell: 
      cmd: pip --version || /usr/bin/python /tmp/get-pip.py
```

- [Use of `&&` and `||` operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24684/)
- [Boolean operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449742/6771046)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily bypass both tasks by using the `creates` parameter which exists for `shell` and `uri`. It expects a filename which will be checked for existence. If the file exists the task will not be run.

***Note**: In my below not entirely tested example, I infered that your script installs the binary in `/usr/local/bin/pip`. Adapt to the exact installation location if different.*

```yaml
---
- name: Install pip
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    pip_location: /usr/local/bin/pip

  tasks:
    - name: Download pip installer
      get_url:
        url: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
        dest: /tmp/get-pip.py
        creates: "{{ pip_location }}"

    - name: Install pip
      shell:
        cmd: /usr/bin/python /tmp/get-pip.py
        creates: "{{ pip_location }}"
```

References:

- [`creates` parameter in `shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-creates)
- [`creates` parameter in `uri` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-creates)

Answer (score 1):

This nice guy [William Yeh](https://github.com/William-Yeh) has written a nice [playbook](https://github.com/William-Yeh/ansible-uwsgi/blob/master/tasks/install-pip.yml) exactly for that purpose:

```yaml
---
# file: tasks/install-pip.yml
# Mini installer for pip; only to enable the Ansible `pip` module.
#
# For full installer, use something like:
# 
#  - Stouts.python
#  - bobbyrenwick.pip
#
# @see https://github.com/gmacon/ansible-pip/blob/variable_executables/tasks/main.yml
#

- name: check to see if pip is already installed
  command: "pip --version"
  ignore_errors: true
  register: pip_is_installed
  changed_when: false

- block:

    - name: download get-pip.py
      get_url: url=https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  dest=/tmp
    
    - name: install pip
      command: "python /tmp/get-pip.py"
    
    - name: delete get-pip.py
      file: state=absent path=/tmp/get-pip.py

  when: pip_is_installed.rc != 0
```