# How 'not to run multiple times' command/shell task in Ansible playbook

Tags: sass, ansible, ansible-facts

I have a task in Ansible to install SASS utilities via RubyGems option, which works well without any issues. If I re-run the same playbook again, it will try to re-install this utility again.

In this case, how to run it once that are using command or shell usage in Ansible playbook. I have somehow handled it not to run the installation by using 'when' option, but need a guidance for better logic/implementation

Task Info:

```
- name: Install SASS packages by using npm utility.
  command: /usr/bin/npm install -g sass
```

To eliminate re-running the above command task in Ansible playbook, I am using below validation logic and added 'when' option as provided below. Is this fine or do we have a better way of handling this one?

```
- name: Validation of SASS packages availability.
  shell: /usr/local/bin/sass --version
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"

- name: Install SASS packages by using npm utility.
  command: /usr/bin/npm install -g sass
  when: "'No such file or directory' in result.stdout"
```

Results:

```
TASK [mean-stack : Validation of SASS packages availability.] ************************************************************************************
changed: [linuxosdev003.local.lab]

TASK [mean-stack : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [linuxosdev003.local.lab] => {
    "msg": "1.47.0 compiled with dart2js 2.15.1"
}

TASK [mean-stack : Install SASS packages by using npm utility.] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [linuxosdev003.local.lab]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************
linuxosdev003.local.lab    : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Have you tried using the purposed module instead: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/npm_module.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid `command` or `shell` whenever possible, if you want an idempotent playbook. Especially your example - remove `sass` and try your playbook. It should fail. Either check if the file exists

```
- name: "Check, if file exists"
  stat:
    path: "/usr/local/bin/sass"
  register: sass_installed
```

But - as already commented - use an ansible module to install NPM packages, like you would do with system packages (`package` or `yum` or `apt`) or Python modules (with `pip`). The module is also available in the last RedHat releease 2.9 under https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/npm_module.html and should be as easy:

```
- name: "Install NPM package: sass"
  npm:
    name: "sass"
```

If you need to install more then one NPM package, you could loop over them

```
- name: "Install NPM packages"
  npm:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "package1"
    - "package2"
```

Answer (score 1):

As @β.εηοιτ.βε and @TRW already mentioned, using a module will eliminate the need for such checks.

However, if it is as simple as checking whether a path exists, then [command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/command_module.html) itself can be used like:

```yaml
- name: Install SASS packages by using npm utility.
  command:
    cmd: /usr/bin/npm install -g sass
    creates: /usr/local/bin/sass
```

This is equal to your `when` condition, i.e. command will run when the path given in `creates` is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Whereby I prefer the solution from @β.εηοιτ.βε and @TRW if package managers are available for the tasks, sometimes it might be necessary to stay on the `shell` module. For such cases I use the similar approach like in the original question.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test.example.com
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Gather installed Java version, if there is any
    shell:
      cmd: java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | cut -d '"' -f 2
    register: result
    check_mode: false
    changed_when: false
    failed_when: result.rc != 0 and result.rc != 127

  - name: Set default version, if there is no
    set_fact:
      result:
        stdout_lines: "0.0.0_000"
    when: "'command not found' in result.stdout"
    check_mode: false

  - name: Report result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
    check_mode: false
```

Based on the installed version an installer or updater would be called to install or update to the latest version if necessary.

**Thanks to**

- [Why does Java version go to `stderr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483443/)

Comment: Great responses from ```TRW    β.εηοιτ.βε    seshadri_c```  and also from @U880D on this question. Though I got an answer/logic to use 'when' in the playbook, I will stick with npm module to make more idempotent. Thanks again!