# Why can't I store a bash command substitution output as a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script that populates a configuration file and it needs to get the Java version and vendor.  I read that the best way to get the Java vendor is to run `java -XshowSettings:properties -version`.  My plan is to use bash regex to get the version and vendor, but storing the command output as a variable is proving trickier than I initially thought.

Here's a code snippet from my script:

```
settings_output="$(${java_command} -XshowSettings:properties -version)"
echo "Output: ${settings_output}"
```

When that runs, I get the following output (ellipses used to abbreviate):

```
Property settings:
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    ...

openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
Output:
```

But what I expect to get is:

```
Output: Property settings:
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    ...

openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I don't understand:

1. Why the output of the bash command isn't being stored in the variable.
2. Why the output is being displayed upon execution.  I haven't touched local echo at all, but I don't recall other command substitutions (at least using `$(COMMAND)` syntax) doing this.

My goal isn't to print the variable out for the user, but because I'm debugging, I found it necessary.

I'm new to bash (and shell) scripting and this is probably me being a complete bonehead, but hopefully someone can help me out.  I figured it was an error with multi-line output, but neither of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable) two [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) held an answer to my problem.  I've even tried declaring an array with each line of the output as elements, but no dice.

Is it obvious to anyone what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The program must be writing its output to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: simple fix (re: capturing stderr): `settings_output="$(java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1)"`; I don't work (much) with `java` so not sure if there's a way to get `java` to write this particular set of output directly to stdout

Comment: @markp-fuso you don't need to redirect, just [tell java to print on stdout using `--version` instead of `-version`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483519/995714)

Comment: @phuclv hmmmm, the suggestion (use `--version` to send output to stdout) appears to be dependent on the version of `java`; for `cygwin / java 1.8.0_231` the `--version` generates an error (`unrecognized option: --version`), while for `ubuntu / openjdk 11.0.21` the `--version` option is valid and the version info is sent to stdout but the properties data is still sent to stderr (and OP is looking for a way to direct both properties and version to stdout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-X` options write their output to standard error, so they won't be mixed in with the regular output of the program. This is in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html)

> `-X`
> Prints the help on extra options to the error stream.

So redirect stderr to stdout so it will be captured.

```
settings_output="$(${java_command} -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
settings_output="$(${java_command} -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1)"
```

because this `java` command write the output on `STDERR`.

Check: [Confused about stdin, stdout and stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr)